# Python-firebase work with firebase-storage

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am read documentation about python-firebase here

http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/

But I didn't see anything about firebase-storage.

Do you guys know can this library work with storage or only with database.

Or do you know better wrapper for Firebase-Storage.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`google-cloud`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) python client:

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('<your-bucket-name>')
blob = bucket.blob('my-test-file.txt')
blob.upload_from_string('this is test content!')
```

Comment: Yes I am test this library. But do you know how to grab URL of image when Image is uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple python wrapper for the Firebase API with `pyrebase` by thisbeijim. You can look at firebase storage; by the way, when you use the `pyrebase` wrapper, you can use firebase services like: authentic, database and storage.

https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is get the imageURL and safe in a database what you have to do is make a firebase function (triguer for firebaseDatabase). Where when you upload a image it send the url to the database.

for More information: [Firebase Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)